# Java server thread and C client socket connection

Tags: java, c

I'm trying to send texts from a C client to a list of Java subscribers (listening on different ports).

To do that, I scroll the list of subscribers, make the connection to the different subscribers and send the text to them.

However, the connection to the subscriber fails.

JAVA SERVER THREAD:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private static ServerSocket _ss;
    private static DataInputStream _in = null;
    private static DataOutputStream _out = null;
    private static BufferedReader _br = null;

    private static String _topic = null;

    public ServerThread(String string, ServerSocket ss, String topic) {
        super(string);
        _ss = ss;
        _topic = topic;
    }

    public void run() {
      String text;

        try {
            System.out.println("Listening on port " + _ss.getLocalPort());

            while(true) {
                 // Waiting connections             
                Socket sc = _ss.accept();

                // Input
                _in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
                _br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_in));

                // Get text
                while((text = _br.readLine()) != null) {
                   System.out.println("MESSAGE FROM " + _topic + " : " + text);
                }
            }

        } catch(IOException e) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }

}
```

SEND TEXT TO SUBSCRIBERS:

```
int send_text_subscriber(char *tp, char *text) {
    struct topic *t;
    struct subscriber *s;
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in subscriber;

    t = find_topic(tp);

    if(t != NULL) {
        s = LIST_FIRST(&t->s_head);

        if(!LIST_EMPTY(&t->s_head)) {
            while(s != NULL) {
                /* Open socket */
                    if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
                        perror("socket");
                        return -1;
                    }

                /* Set address */
                subscriber.sin_family = AF_INET;
                subscriber.sin_addr = s->address.sin_addr;
                subscriber.sin_port = s->address.sin_port;

                /* Connect */
                    if(connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&subscriber, sizeof(subscriber)) == -1) {
                        printf("\n  > Error in the connection to the subscriber %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(subscriber.sin_addr), subscriber.sin_port);
                        return -1;
                    }

                /* Send text */
                    printf("\n  > Sending text to %s:%d... ", inet_ntoa(subscriber.sin_addr), subscriber.sin_port);
                    if(write(sd, text, strlen(text)) == -1) {
                        perror("write");
                        return -1;
                    }
                    printf("[OK]\n\n");

                s = LIST_NEXT(s, entries);
            }
        } 
    }
```

I create the server thread when the subscription to a topic is succeded:

```
static int subscribe(String topic) {
        try {
            // Open connection to the broker
            _sd = new Socket(_server, _port);
            _ss = new ServerSocket(0); // Server Socket Descriptor

            _in = new DataInputStream(_sd.getInputStream());
            _out = new DataOutputStream(_sd.getOutputStream());

            // Send type operation
            _out.write(SUBSCRIBE.getBytes(), 0, SUBSCRIBE.length());
            _out.write('\0');
            _out.flush();
            // Send the topic to subscribe to
            _out.write(topic.getBytes(), 0, topic.length());
            _out.write('\0');
            _out.flush();
            // Send listening port
            _out.writeShort((short)_ss.getLocalPort());
            _out.flush();

            // Get response from the broker
            if(_in.read() == 0) {
                System.out.println("c> SUBSCRIBE OK");

                // Create server thread
                ServerThread t = new ServerThread("server", _ss, topic);
                t.start();

            } else {
                System.out.println("c> SUBSCRIBE FAIL");
            }

            // Close connection
            _in.close();
      _sd.close();

        } catch(IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error in the connection to the broker " + _server + ":" + _port);
    }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown how the Java `ServerSocket` is constructed. What the program prints is of little or no interest, as they are just messages of your own devising,

Comment: Would be very helpful if you could create a [mcve]. ("complete" in the sense that we are able to run it ourselves.)

Comment: And when you get an error from a system call, use `perror()` and friends, not just some random text of your own devising. You got a connect error. What was it?

Comment: I've update the code to show where I create the ServerSocket. The perror message is "Connection refused".

Comment: Don't use DataInputStream to read text, it adds nothing but confusion.

Comment: "Connection Refused" means there is no service listening on that port.

Comment: You don't need to send the port the client is listening as the server already knows this.

Comment: You don't need to flush() an unbuffered stream

Comment: Once you get the connection connecting, you will have a problem that the Java server expects lines of text (which finish with a newline) however you are sending string terminated with a `\0` byte.  I suggest you decide which one it should be and do the same thing at both ends.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I send the listening-port because the subscriber connects to the broker to make subscription of any topic (main thread in Java). When subscription is successful, then the subscriber creates a server thread to listen on another port to receive texts from that topic, while in the main thread it still sends request to the broker for more topics subscriptions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey At the same time, the broker is waiting for subscriptions from subscriber clients and texts from publisher clients. So when a publisher updates a determinated topic, then the broker sends this text to all subscribers from that topic.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's the reason why I need to send the 'listening port' from the subscriber, because it needs another port to receive the text from the topics subscribed.

Comment: @nash ok, that makes sense though I would just use one port for subscriptions and events.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, the protocol indicates that I have to use another port... I'm thinking that probably I need another thread to handler this sending text...

Comment: @nash can you provide a link to this protocol or is not a public one? You can use another thread, it would be simpler to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem changing two things:

```
subscriber.sin_port = htons(s->address.sin_port);
```

1. I needed to add **`htons`**, because the address stores the port with the format "from network to host" (`ntohs`).
2. And finally, I forgot to **close the connection**.